# Android: Correctly position buttons inside layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a following layout :

[image]

```
<LinearLayout //container, should adjust height based on CONTENT view height
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:padding="20dp">
     <RelativeLayout //this is the CONTENT view height
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5">....</RelativeLayout>
...
    <RelativeLayout //this is the button layout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

          <Button android:layout_width="40sp" android:layout_height="40sp"/>
          <Button android:layout_width="40sp" android:layout_height="40sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the height of the container (`LinearLayout`) to be adjusted to contain all the views in the `RelativeLayout` (shown on the left, let's call it **CONTAINER**).

Then, there are two buttons in the `RelativeLayout` (shown on the right). I need to align them on top and bottom borders of `RelativeLayot`, correspondingly. What's really important, is that the height of the buttons' container should be the same (should correspond) to the height of the **CONTAINER**.

The problem is, if I try to use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` attributes for the buttons, they will stretch the container height, and it will take the whole screen height.

So, what magic should I use to do the trick? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to align your right relative layout top and bottom to the left one.
Try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout //container, should adjust height based on CONTENT view height
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:padding="20dp">
     <RelativeLayout //this is the CONTENT view height
            android:id="@+id/contentRL"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">....</RelativeLayout>
...
    <RelativeLayout //this is the button layout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/contentRL"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/contentRL"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

          <Button android:layout_width="40sp" 
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
          <Button android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm, `RelativeLayout` seems not to have such (or similar attributes). Any other way?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it again and let me know.
(Changed main Layout to Relative and adapt position of childs RelativeLayouts).

Comment: This will not work - Views with layout_weight should have a parent LinearLayout. But using your advice I found the way to do what I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:padding="20dp">
     <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"></RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
          <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, this is undesired, because this will stretch the root LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on a hint provided by Damien R. above I successfully accomplished the task by doing following:

- Use `RelativeLayout` as a root with paramters `layout_width="wrap_content"`, `layout_height="wrap_content"`
- Use `LinearLayout` as a "wrapper" around container `RelativeLayout`s. This is because I need to lay out these containers using `layout_weight` attribute.
- `RelativeLayout` `layout_height` should be `fill_parent`. No need to use `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/..."` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/..."` in the `RelativeLayout` attributes. This will only work if `RelativeLayout` is a child `View` of another `RelativeLayout`, and that's not the case, because I need to use `LinearLayout`'s weight

The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ticketbackground"
        android:id="@+id/ticket_layout"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentRL"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        </RelativeLayout>

<!--second column-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">
              ...
        </RelativeLayout>
<!--third column with buttons-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sdfsdf"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <Button...
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
            <Button...
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```